# help testing hera on hp stream 11 with windows 10

Tags: release-hera

Hello im wanting to get elementary os on a hp stream 11 y0xx the specs are 4gb ram 64 bit processor and a intel celeron n3060 @1.60 ghz and i would like to know how well it will i cant make a demo disc thats why thanks

Answer (score 0):

In any case you have to create a bootable USB stick or DVDR(W) to install it, which loads a live session where you can check how everything works and then you get to install it if you wish.